# How to design domain classes in Grails?

Tags: grails, orm, domain-driven-design, grails-orm

*Given these functional requirements:*

**User Management**

1. Administrator
2. Librarian
3. Borrower

*The users have the option of logging-in via OpenID.

**Property Management**

1. Book
2. Memorandum
3. Circular
4. License

Normally, I would implement these in Java as:

```
interface User {}
class Librarian implements User {}
class Administrator implements User {}
class Borrower implements User {}

class OpenID {} //all Users HAS AN OpenID attribute (NULL if non-openId login)

interface Property{}
class Book implements Property{}
class Memorandum implements Property{}
class Circular implements Property{}
class License implements Property{}
```

But our project will use Groovy & Grails, which I haven't experience using yet. My question is,
how should the **domain** classes be designed based on the requirements above? I can't use an interface, and it seems inheritance is not a good practice. My idea is to use **composition**, though I'm quite bothered by the database tables that would be generated. What are the best practices in this situation?

Comment: Sometimes its easier to start with the database schema and work backwards. Try thinking of it that way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well first of all lets correct it, you can use `inheritance` in this case. You just need to change the convention of `has a` relationship to `is a` relationship.

Few factors to keep note of:
1. Grails works on convention over configuration.
2. You can use GORM which wraps the persistence layer and creates an Object Mapping for the underlying persistence layer with the help of Hibernate.

As per your functional requirement:-

If you do not want to have the `User` as part of persistence you can have an `abstract`  class `User` which can hold the common properties of the User including the `openId` attribute. It has to be placed in `src\groovy` directory as per convention (since the base class is abstract, dependency injection will be defied)

The same goes for `Property`. Abstract `Property` class in `src\groovy`.

Now coming to the business models, `extend` each of the concrete entities (`domain` classes) from the `abstract` parent.

Summary:-

- Create grails app
- Under src\groovy(for example, I am considering a basic structure):

User.groovy:-

```
abstract class User{
    String name
    String emailId
    OpenID openId
}
```

Property.groovy:-

```
abstract class Property{
    String propertyName
}
```

- Under `grails-app/domain`:

Librariran.groovy:-

```
class Librarian extends User{
   //Attributes specific to Librariran
   static constraints = {
   }

   static mapping = {
   }
}
```

Book.groovy:-

```
class Book extends Property{
    //Attributes specific to Book
       static constraints = {
       }

       static mapping = {
       }
}
```

So on and so forth. Groovy objects under grails-app/domain are considered concrete entities by Grails convention. More information you can obviously find [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html). You can also use composition if you come across scenarios, in fact I already mentioned that in `User` having `OpenId`.

Note:- This is context to latest version of Grails (> 2.x)

Comment: Thanks! But as I understand it, if I put the abstract classes in src/groovy, there will be no User and Property tables created in the database. Am I correct? I'm assuming our client would want a table for all Users and for all Properties.

Comment: Yes, in that case you can have both of them as domain objects inside grails-app/domain.