# Grails: domain class inheritance best practice

Tags: hibernate, grails, orm

I my application I have users - many types of users. I have a hierarchy of them like

```
User
Worker extends User
Director extends Worker
Manager extends User
```

They have different functionalities, data etc. but all of them are first-class citizens.
User has ability to log-in - fields like password, username etc.

Now I try to model this structure up in a database - or rather find best solution to this problem.
As I used a PostgreSQL - tables inheritance its most clear solution for me - this is, however, not supported by Hibernate at all. 
Options in Grails are - table per hierarchy - which I dont like for many reasons (not-nullable columns are one of them) or table per class. This may work, however I found that generated tables lacks one of very important thing - a foreign key.
Lets say I have user table, thats fine, it uses its own sequence. They there is a worker table which have fields from worker class and references an user by its ID - technically speaking I have two records building up a Worker class when mapping in application - thats fine, unless I see that worker id column is not a foreign key to user id - which is trivial to add in plain SQL and works well.
I cannot find solution how to do this programatically in Grails.

But now I realized that maybe I'm missing something and my whole idea is wrong - so I would like to ask - what is the best idea to sole this issue? 
I know for sure that using mapping like one-to-one is unacceptable.

Comment: Generally when you go to production you will be using database migrations, so you will have control over any foreign keys. It's not something that has to be done programmatically via Grails.

Comment: see
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312180/how-to-design-domain-classes-in-grails>