# grails best practice for designing domain class with inherintance?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I just trying to use GRAILS 2.3.x for my project .. and I have 3 type of loans.

1. standard loan (flat interest rate)
2. anuity loan (with anuity interest rate)
3. employee loan (almost same with standard loan but with different rules of payment)

Usually in java we create interface for the Loan and then inherit them ... could we create interface as domain class ? (should I put the interface inside domain class or inside other directory ?)

should I put the interest rate and installments calculation inside the domain class or separated it into the grails services ?

thank you ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312180/how-to-design-domain-classes-in-grails). To add few points in addition to the answer, you can also consider [tablePerSubclass](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/GORM.html#inheritanceInGORM) strategy if you need tables for each type of loan.

Comment: This can be achieved by declaring `tablePerHierarchy false` in the base Loan domain. If you do not want Loan table at all, then Loan can become abstract class and move to src/groovy. A new and 3rd way of inheritance is tablePerConcreteClass (which I have not used yet) can be used in each subclass where the base table Loan will not be created by can be in grails-app/domain.